# Quick question on partial derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can one have the following: $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\right)?$$

Comment: Yes, that's the [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

Comment: Assuming $F$ is multivariable, are you looking for the multivariable chain rule?

Comment: Are there any restrictions to this?

Comment: @AndrewLi F is indeed multivariable. But what do I need for this to work?

Comment: @Hello_World If $F$ is multivariable, you would need to also add the partial derivative of $F$ with respect to all other variables multiplied by the partial derivative of that variable with respect to $v$.

Answer (score 4):

In general if $F=F(x,y)$ but after we have $x=x(v,w)$ and $y=y(v,w)$ then $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v},$$
and
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial w},$$
are available.

Comment: From them you can see that if $\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}=0$ we get your formula